# You, you two, you people and you'se

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, pronouns

I understand that you'se is not considered a formal English word by the Oxford. Colloquially, many people use the word you'se all the time in common conversation. As such, there is a gap in formal English for pointing out the subject as two or more people being adressed. 
For example, if I were to say

> You should buy that Lear Jet.

It would be pronounced the same as

> You [people] should buy that Lear Jet.

The only thing separating the two statements is context, which is sometimes hard to encapsulate across different media etc.

Why then is you'se not a formal word for this situation? 
For example:

> You'se [all people being addressed] should buy that Lear Jet.

It becomes obvious that verbally, the pronoun of the conversation is now referencing more than one person and dispelling confusion.
I understand that *ye* was the Middle English form of this word.
As such, why is *you'se* frowned upon?

**Edit:** For non-Australians, the word *you'se* is equivalent to *y'all* and can be substituted throughout my question.

Comment: Have you really heard "you'se" used as a subject, before a word that begins with a consonant? "You lot should..." or "Y'all should..." sound natural enough, but "you'se should" sounds quite odd, I think. I've always heard "you'se" or "yinz" as an object or object of a preposition, I think. (Although neither is terribly common in my area.)

Comment: Absolutely. Where I'm from (Australia) this is a very common phrase as I've described. I would say that Y'all is the American equivalent of the Australian you'se and is almost completely not used.

Comment: Why close? Deficiencies in the language are no embarrassment, let the Q stay, I'd say.

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/youse

Comment: I've never seen an apostrophe in the spelling of "youse"; What part of Australia is this variant from?

Comment: Odd that no one has mentioned "All of you ..." as an alternative to clarify the plurality.  Personally I think it sounds better that "You people ...".

Comment: I was actually unsure of the spelling of youse, as I've never seen it written

Comment: @Mothermole1 Sh... You are disclosing that you never looked up a dictionary (or GoogleSearch) before asking the question. :)

Comment: I typically see this word spelled as "yous" and is often found in American caricatures of certain immigrants/ethic groups. I want to say Italian mobsters but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contemporary English does not have a second-person plural.  To make up for this deficiency, various dialectical forms have evolved.  *Youse*, *you'se*, *you-all*, and several other forms have evolved, but none are universally accepted.

"You people" is potentially derogatory and might best be avoided.

Comment: The situation is no better than with the inclusive *we*.

Comment: While this answer does provide useful information, it doesn't appear to answer the question "why is you'se frowned upon?"

Comment: @user867   Thanks!  Regional dialects tend to be looked upon as with a degree of distrust by those who did not grow up hearing and speaking them because they are "non-standard."    "Youse" is sometimes used as a singular pronoun, a fact that was not mentioned in my answer.  Maybe I don't hear it because I grew up using you(s) and y'all(pl).

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin Thanks for providing that information. Might I suggest you edit it in to the answer, since it's what was asked for?

Answer (score 0):

> **[youse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/youse)**
>   Pronunciation: /juːz/
>   (also **yous**)
>   *pronoun*
>   *dialect*
>   you (usually more than one person).

Chiefly **US**:

> **[youse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/youse)**
>   *pron*. *Chiefly Northern U.S.*
>   You. Used in addressing two or more people or referring to two or more people, one of whom is addressed. See Notes at you-all, you-uns.
>   [you + -s.]

Sometimes as *youse guys* [Boston, New York and Philadelphia]:

> [**yous**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yous#English)
>   - The term is predominantly used in Scotland and Ireland and throughout Australia, as well as overseas areas of previous Irish emigration e.g. some parts of the US (Boston, MA and Philadelphia, PA) and northern Nova Scotia and Lanark Ontario/Canada and South Auckland, New Zealand. It also occurs in Scouse.
>   - *Yous(e)* as a plural is found in Australia, England, Scotland, Ireland, New Zealand, South Africa, parts of the northern United States, and parts of Ontario. *Yous(e)* as a singular is found in Philadelphia, New York, Boston and scattered throughout working class Italian-American communities in the Rust Belt.

Comment: There's a different (AAVE) use for *youse* as well?: *you is* -- as in *Youse a damn fool* http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/youse

Comment: While this answer does provide useful information, it doesn't appear to answer the question "why is you'se frowned upon?"

Comment: @Hugo  *you'se* is **not** frowned upon, thus that part of the question is a NARQ. It's not listed as a formal word because it has the status of 'dialect' -- dialect is not 'low English,' please note.

Comment: *You'se* may be frowned upon in formal writing. // The other question -- "Why then is you'se not a formal word for this situation?" -- is not addressed here either.

Comment: @Hugo You are indeed aware that dialects are not formal. They are inherently culture-dependent. Formal language is a mostly unified structure to be understood universally. I don't consider any of this discussion relevant exclusively to *youse*. Every such word is geography/culture-specific.

Comment: In some parts of Ireland "ye" is very commonly used instead of "youse".